# Remove binding from TFS

Tags: tfs, workspace

Somehow my workspace have been mapped against two accounts. The first one doesn't have access to TFS at all.

How can I delete one of the mappings without removing any files? I have lot of files checked out and I can't check in since the first account is used every time I try.

I've never been logged in with the first account, only the second. The TFS server is in a second domain, so that might have something to do with the problem.

```
Collection: http://srv00181.XXXX.com:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
Workspace Owner            Computer  Comment
--------- ---------------- --------- -----------------------------------
BORUTV587 ABC12345\BO84194 BORUTV587
BORUTV587 ABC12345\BA84194 BORUTV587
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had for some reason BO84194 saved under `Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager`.

I removed that account and everything started working again.

One can use

> tf workspace /delete /server:http://srv00181.XXXX.com:8080/tfs/defaultcollection WORKSPACENAME;DOMAIN\ACCOUNT

to delete workspace mappings (which I did for BO)

To list all workspaces, simply use:

> tf workspaces /s:http://srv00181.XXXX.com:8080/defaultcollection